# Correct way to navigate to a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a login sequence in which after the user is successfully logged, the tab bar controller will appear.

It seems like I cannot **Edit -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller** to a **Tab Bar Controller**, so I want to know what is the right way to present a tab bar controller after the login operation: which controller should be first in order to jump to the tab bar controller after logging, and also since the tab bar controller is the first in the storyboard, how to change it so the login one would be the first? (Using interface builder)

**Edit:** The question is probably not clear enough, so let me decorate it a little bit:

The apple documentation says **Navigation Controller** will provide a stack behavior to push and pop view controllers. Given the fact that once you log in, you don't want a back button to the login screen, I'm guessing that is not the correct controller to use.

So I am guessing a View Controller should do the job: presenting username, password text boxes and a log in button. From this point, once the user press the login button (and the credentials are fine), we want to navigate to the **Tab Bar Controller**.

Question 1: am I right assuming that a **View Controller** is what would do the job? if so, how do you show the next **Tab Bar Controller**

Question 2: Right now my storyboard starts with the Tab Bar Controller, how do I modify it so it starts with the View Controller, as I can't find any documentation regarding that issue nor an intuitive way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: yes, a view controller will do the job of handling the login. After the login is complete, transition to the tab bar controller by initiating a segue transition with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Answer 2: change the initial view controller by selecting the view controller you want to be presented when the app starts (in this case the login controller) on the storyboard. In the attributes Inspector, select the "Is Initial View Controller` checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

use a view controller for login credentials and when success, present the tabbar controller by `performSegueWithIdentifier` i.e., login viewcontroller  **tabbarcontroller** not the viewcontroller associated to tabbarcontroller and for each rootviewcontroller embed it in navigation controller. i will give an example.

[image]

**so that for each tab in tabbarcontroller there will be a seperate stack because we have seperate navigation controller for each tab**. Hope it helps. Happy coding